# ng-class condition changes, but not updating classes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

I have a very strange issue. I have to set an `active` class on the appropriate `<li>` when the `$scope.selectedCat == cat.id`. The list is generated with ng-repeat. If selectedCat is false, the 'Browse All Categories' list item (outside of ng-repeat) is set to active. `setCat()` sets the value of the `$scope.selectedCat` variable:

```
<div id="cat-list" ng-controller="CatController">
    <li ng-class="{'active': {{selectedCat == false}}}">
        <a>
            <div class="name" ng-click="setCat(false)" >Browse All Categories</div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="has-subcat" ng-repeat="cat in cats | filter:catsearch" ng-class="{'active': {{selectedCat == cat.id}}}">
        <a>
            <div cat class="name" ng-click="setCat({{cat.id}})" ng-bind-html="cat.name | highlight:catsearch"></div>
        </a>
    </li>
</div>
```

When the page loads, everything works fine (snapshot from FireBug):

```
<li ng-class="{'active': true}" class="ng-scope active">
<!-- ngRepeat: cat in cats | filter:catsearch -->
<li class="has-subcat ng-isolate-scope" ng-repeat="cat in cats | filter:catsearch" ng-class="{'active': false}">
```

However when I set $scope.selectedClass to a `cat.id` value, the condition within ng-class gets evaluated correctly, but ng-class won't update the classes accordingly:

```
<li ng-class="{'active': false}" class="ng-scope active"> <!--Right here!-->
<!-- ngRepeat: cat in cats | filter:catsearch -->
<li class="has-subcat ng-isolate-scope" ng-repeat="cat in cats | filter:catsearch" ng-class="{'active': true}">
```

Please note that in the first line active class stays set, while ng-class evaluates to false. In the last line active is not set, while ng-class evaluates to true.

Any ideas why it doesn't work? What's the correct Angular way of doing this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Replace:

```
ng-class="{'active': {{selectedCat == cat.id}}}"
```

With:

```
ng-class="{'active': selectedCat == cat.id}"
```

You never need to nest those curly braces like that, in Angular.

Have a look at the [`ng-class` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) for some more examples.

Comment: You may also use a function that gets the class name if it is dynamic, that would help if you need classes like: active-1 (and -1 depends on something else), just concat would not refresh if the "-1" changes to "-2".

Answer (score 13):

Instead of

```
ng-class="{'active': {{selectedCat == cat.id}}}"
```

use

```
ng-class="{active: selectedCat == cat.id}"
```

Comment: I have the **single quotes** also removed. You don't need that around 'active'. I was not allowed to add it as a comment to your answer, that is why posted as a separate answer. Apology since you felt bad.

Answer (score 6):

Hi i'm also facing the same problem. i solved the problem by the way instead of assigning the value directly to ng-class, call the separate method and return the value.

ex :

```
ng-class="getStyleClass(cat)"

$scope.getStyleClass = function(cat)  {   
      return "active: selectedCat == cat.id";  
}
```

roughly i coded. please change the method as per your requirement.

Comment: That's crazy. Thought it would behave the same as when using the [well unknown] syntax of `ng-class="{ true: 'active', false: 'muted' }[x == y]"`. This syntax always rebinds / debinds the classes.

Comment: Scratch that. This isn't working for me. It still puts the style on each [selected] item, but when `$scope.selected` changes (via my `isSelected(date) -> return this.selected === date`) each of the consecutively clicked items retain this style upon other selections.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the answer @Cerbrus gave:

> Replace:
>
> `ng-class="{'active': {{selectedCat == cat.id}}}"`
>
> With:
>
> `ng-class="{'active': selectedCat == cat.id}"`

I had an issue with an expression using a filter, that would not evaluate properly without double curly braces `{{ }}`.

Example: `ng-class="{'active': {{ selectedCat | filter:catType }} == cat.id}"`

I solved it by putting parentheses instead of curly braces.

Solution: `ng-class="{'active': ( selectedCat | filter:catType ) == cat.id}"`

Answer (score 0):

Did you solve it?

In my opinion you should use

`ng-class="{'active': {{controller.selectedCat == cat.id}}}"`

With:

`ng-class="{'active': controller.selectedCat == cat.id}"`

this will help you.